# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

Hi So I created this function called runloopg(x,y,z) that produces a list but I can't call an item on the list:

```
p=runloopg(10,0.1,6)
<generator object rtpairs at 0x000000000BAF1F78>
[(0,0,0,0,0,1), (0.01,0,0,0,0,1), (0.0062349,0.00781831,0,0,0,1), (-0.00222521,0.00974928,0,0,0,1), (-0.00900969,0.00433884,0,0,0,1), (0.0549583,-0.0712712,0,0,0,1), (0.0627244,-0.0645419,0,0,0,1), (0.0696727,-0.0569711,0,0,0,1), (0.0757128,-0.0486577,0,0,0,1), (0.0807659,-0.0397099,0,0,0,1), (0.084766,-0.0302444,0,0,0,1), (0.0876611,-0.0203847,0,0,0,1), (0.0894134,-0.0102592,0,0,0,1)]
```

However when I call an item on my list as so:

```
p[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-240-a69904524460> in <module>()
----> 1 p[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is the code for runloopg:

```
import numpy
import raytracer29

def rtpairs(R, N):
    for i in range(len(R)):
        r=R[i]
        n=N[i]
        for j in range(n):
            t = j*2*numpy.pi/n
            yield r,t

def rtuniform(n, rmax, m):
    R=numpy.arange(0,rmax,rmax/n)
    N=numpy.arange(1, n*m, m)
    return rtpairs(R, N)

def runloopg(n, rmax, m):
    #print  rtuniform(n, rmax, m)
    bund = []
    for r,t in rtuniform(n, rmax, m):
        myRay = raytracer29.Ray(r * numpy.cos(t), r * numpy.sin(t),0,0,0,1)        
        bund.append(myRay)
    return bund
```

Comment: Your function returns generator object no the list, thus loop through it and get the value you want.

Comment: just debug your code and try  dir(yourobject), and see , what it returns, I mean see the methods and attributes and find out which type of object u have.

Comment: @MairajKhan the error already says *exactly* what type of object `p` is - `NoneType` (and therefore, `p` is `None`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A generator object is returned. Once you used a generator, it's exhausted and you can't use it again.

But you can take all of it's values as a list:

```
p = list(runloopg(10,0.1,6))
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't actually explain the OP's error - a generator doesn't yield `None`, much less somehow *become* `None`, after it has exhausted - it becomes an empty iterable (ie, it raises `StopIteration` immediately whenever you try to iterate it).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error 'NoneType' object is not iterable when I type p = list(runloopg(10,0.1,6))

Comment: I have added the function definition in the original post. Can you identify the problem and find the solution?

Comment: Passing the return value of your function to `list` doesn't make any change since your function returns a list already.

Comment: Answer downvoted cause it's _obviously_ not the explanation (nor the solution).

Comment: @bruno Obviously :) I know that, i commented in BurhanKhalid's answer. So, this is pretty much a random guess.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the relevant code - your function's definition - but very obviously this function returns `None`.

**edit:** Ok from the snippet you posted `runloopg` does indeed return a list so the problem is elsewhere. I see that your snippet starts with a commented out `print` statement printing the return value of a call to `rtuniform`, and this matches what you posted of your interactive session. My guess is that you were executing an older version of the function that just printed and exited immediatly (implicitely returning `None`), then you edited your code but failed to properly reload your function.

Comment: I've added the function's definition in the original post. Can you identify the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry but no - your function is actually returning a list so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method is returning a generator, you need to consume it:

```
for i in runloopg(10,0.1,6):
   print(i)

p = list(runloopg(10,0.1,6))

# If you just want the first item:

first_item = next(runloopg(10,0.1,6))
```

Comment: I posted a similar answer, but somehow i don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error 'NoneType' object is not iterable when I type p = list(runloopg(10,0.1,6))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `runloopg` function is missing a `return`. So, it does something like this:

```
def runloopg():
   [(0,0,0,0,0,1), (0.01,0,0,0,0,1), (0.0062349,0.00781831,0,0,0,1)] # and the rest
```

or this:

```
def runloop():
    x = [(0,0,0,0,0,1), (0.01,0,0,0,0,1), (0.0062349,0.00781831,0,0,0,1)] # and the rest
```

instead of this:

```
def runloopg():
    return [(0,0,0,0,0,1), (0.01,0,0,0,0,1), (0.0062349,0.00781831,0,0,0,1)] # and the rest
```

In the first version, that line is run, its result is then immediately discarded, and the function continues. In the second, the result is stored in a variable, and the function continues. In both cases, the function then falls off the end - and Python will return `None` for you when that happens. In the last version, the result you've calculated is returned, and ends up being assigned to `p` - so `p` will be a list, and `p[0]` will work.

Comment: Hi Ivc. I had 'return' in my function definition already. Besides I have added the function definition to the original post. Could you see where the problem may be?